i am using vue-instantsearch with vue2，the ais-Hits widget work fine，but the ais-SearchBox can not render the form css
this is my code
<template>
  <div id="app-search">
    <ais-instant-search :search-client="searchClient" index-name="demo_ecommerce">
      <ais-search-box />
      <ais-hits>
        <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
          <h2>{{ item.name }}</h2>
        </template>
      </ais-hits>
    </ais-instant-search>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch/lite'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      searchClient: algoliasearch(
        'B1G2GM9NG0',
        'aadef574be1f9252bb48d4ea09b5cfe5'
      )
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 1em;
}
</style>

and the final html is
<div class="ais-InstantSearch">
    <div class="ais-SearchBox"></div>
    <div class="ais-Hits">
        <ol class="ais-Hits-list">
            <li class="ais-Hits-item">
                <h2>AT&amp;T GoPhone - Samsung Galaxy Express 3 4G LTE with 8GB Memory Prepaid Cell Phone</h2>
            </li>
            ...
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>

i have tried with a new vue project demo,and it work fine,i don't known why i put the same code in my previous project, the ais-SearchBox doen't work
